# How to cut and append header code into a div tag?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to cut my header code and append into `postTopNotification div`.
Header is too big so I can not paste it into jQuery and append.

I want to know that is there another way to do this? May I cut my code and append into a div?

I want that when I scroll down 100px my header will be show in `postTopNotification div`

This is some of my header code:

```
<header>
    <div class="topMenuWrap">
        <div class="logoWrap">
            <a href="<?php echo site_url();?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/logo.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="topMenu">
        </ul>
        <div class="tip">
        <a href="#">
            <p>Got A Tip ?</p>
            <span>Let Us Know</span>
        </a>
        </div><!--- tip end-->
        <form id="headerSearch">
            <div class="headSearchWrap">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</header>
```

And this is `postTopNotification div`

```
<div class="postTopNotification"></div>
```

Comment: Do you have event listeners on the elements in `<header>` such as the form submit or other events? If so moving it can break all those.

Comment: yes i have like search bar so there is a form and all. and menu loops php and all stuff that a header have.

Comment: Well that doesn't really answer the question asked. Just beware that moving it to a new element can break event listeners

Comment: ok if you know how to move it just do it I can handle other things if they do not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
`$("header").appendTo(".postTopNotification");`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using php why not just do an include in both places, something like this:

```
<?php include 'header.html';?>
```

This would give you one place to load the html from so you don't have to make changes in both places and you don't have to do any additional work once its loaded.

Comment: I know but i cant i just want to move it

Comment: Okay, what about appending it in jquery one smaller portion at a time instead of everything all at once?

Comment: i got it what i want in the last answer thanks for helping